# How can I fix the issue of breakpoints being hit but not showing code in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

When using the visual studio debugger I placed a breakpoint in my adapter, when that breakpoint was hit I got this screen:
[BreakModeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaE0W.png)
I can see in the breakpoints tab that my breakpoint was hit as it is highlighted there but I cannot debug my code.

This also created another problem.

Whenever an event is invoked and our thread comes to execute the method the debugger suddenly loses all ability to show the values of all variables.

when hovering over the tooltip it just shows their name instead of the values, e.g. if I had a variable named seconds that is an integer and has a value of 100 the debugger would show me:

seconds: seconds
instead of 100.

I tried disabling all my extensions, I tried removing and adding Xamarin in tools and features.

[toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCNwr.png)
This is what the process looks like.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does [This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-compatible-code-running-the-selected-debug-engi/70880) help?

Comment: No, my colleague has an older Visual Studio version and it debugs correctly on that.

I just updated to to the latest Visual Studio 2022 version.

Comment: It looks like your debugger is unable to attach to the process and properly debug it. Since you are mentioning Xamarin, either your VS installation is missing some kind of library or there might be bug related to latest VS version. I would try to downgrading to older version if that would resolve the issue and/or complete reinstall of VS.

Comment: I tried reinstalling but that did not work.

Comment: Whenever have a problem with a project/solution after upgrading VS, delete the solution's hidden `.vs` folder, plus all .obj and .bin folders. This fixes any version incompatibilities with internal VS information for that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by simply rolling back to a previous version.

But for the latest version the problem s not fixed. Please refrain from updating to 17.6 as it might break your debugger too.